# Delete specified range of line number from a text file using sed from within PHP

Tags: linux, sed, php

I am trying to delete range of line numbers using sed command within php using exec command. I know how to use sed when substituting values directly within command.

```
exec("sed -i.bak -e '2d;12,17d;57d' $filename", $outputArray);
```

Note: the range will be chosen by the user and hence directly using the above command will not help me; it should be a variable.

For example, I want something like this:

```
<?php
$delete_from_line=35;
$delete_to_line=40;
exec("sed -i.bak -e "$delete_from_line,$delete_to_line" $filename", $outputArray);
?>
```

Comment: Use command `d` to delete a line with `sed`.

Comment: @Cyrus have been trying to use d option with $variable but of no use , can you please be more elaborate ?

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$delete_from_line=35;
$delete_to_line=40;
$filename="/path/to/your/file";

exec('sed -i.bak ' . $delete_from_line . ',' . $delete_to_line . 'd ' . $filename);
?>
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus , that worked :) , but it works only when i execute with `sudo php filename.php` else if i just use `php filename.php` it throws `couldn't open temporary file , permission denied`

Comment: The user (apache, httpd ...) which runs your php code needs write permissions to the directory which contains the file you want to edit.